# How to call data from elsewhere when I click a button in QML

Tags: qt, qml

When I click a button in QML, I want the data from another place that I created before to come to the textfields in my table, how can I do it? Can I do this in QML or do I need to create a separate backend cpp file? Can you help me please?

For example this below code is one row of my table

```
Rectangle{
  border.width: 2
  border.color: "black"
  id:rectangle_mov_mean_nokta_sayisi
  Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
  Layout.preferredWidth: mainWindow.width/8
  Layout.preferredHeight: mainWindow.height/22
  Layout.margins: -3
  Layout.fillWidth: true
  color: row_even
  Text{
    color:normal_text
    id:text_rectangle_mov_mean_nokta_sayisi
    text:"Mov Mean Nokta Sayısı"
    anchors.centerIn: parent
  }
}
Rectangle{
  border.width: 2
  border.color: "black"
  id:rectangle_mov_mean_nokta_sayisi_deger
  Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
  Layout.preferredWidth: mainWindow.width/8
  Layout.preferredHeight: mainWindow.height/22
  Layout.margins: -3
  Layout.fillWidth: true
  color:row_even
  TextField {
    id:textfield_rectangle_mov_mean_nokta_sayisi_deger
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    placeholderText: qsTr("")
    color:normal_text
  }
}
```

There are 20 of these rectangles. When I click a button, a separate value will be displayed for each text field. I need to create these values elsewhere.

Comment: Please show us some more code, what do you already have, how does your model look like.

Answer (score 0):

you should read [Signal and Slots in QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#adding-signals-to-custom-qml-types).

For example :

If you have 3 separate QML files:

In `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("External Components with signals and slots")

    Notifier{
        id : notifierId
        rectColor: "yellowgreen"
        target: receiverId
    }

    Receiver {
        id : receiverId
        rectColor: "dodgerblue"
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        notifierId.notify.connect(receiverId.receiveInfo)//Connect signal to slot
    }
}
```

and in `Receiver.qml` :

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {

    property alias rectColor: receiverRectId.color
    width: receiverRectId.width
    height: receiverRectId.height

    function receiveInfo( count){
        receiverDisplayTextId.text = count
        console.log("Receiver received number : "+ count)
    }



    Rectangle {
        id : receiverRectId
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "red"


        Text {
            id : receiverDisplayTextId
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pointSize: 20
            text : "0"
        }
    }

}
```

and in `Notifier.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {

    property alias rectColor: notifierRectId.color
    width: notifierRectId.width
    height: notifierRectId.height
    property int count: 0
    signal notify( string count)//Declare signal
    property Receiver target : null

    onTargetChanged: {
        notify.connect(target.receiveInfo)
    }


    Rectangle {
        id : notifierRectId
        width: 200
        height: 200
        color: "red"


        Text {
            id : displayTextId
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font.pointSize: 20
            text : count
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                count++
                notify(count)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**you can see that by using signals and slots you can send data from `Notifier.qml` to `Receiver.qml`.**